# CSS selector with hyphen/dash

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the code below I want to select all the elements having a class name that start with "bg-client"

```
<span class="bg-client">Lorem ipsum</span>
<span class="bg-client_a">Lorem ipsum</span>
<span class="bg-client_b">Lorem ipsum</span>
<span class="bg-client_c">Lorem ipsum</span>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
[class^="bg-client"] {}
[class^="bg\2Dclient"] {}
[class^="bg\u002Dclient"] {}
```

Any help ?

Comment: `[class^="bg-client"]` this works fine

Comment: @Pranjal — That's the point

Comment: @Martial - Which browser are you facing this issue? Try reproducing the issue here or in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: so i think your problem is not with the selector but with a priority order or heritage css

Comment: if you have control over the values of the class values, you better use something like `bg-client a`, `bg-client b` and just use a class selector (using `^` is slow)

Comment: I've made a plnkr in case you want to test your (seemingly working) selector  in different browsers http://plnkr.co/edit/hqmHziLvsIe7SfbDbx8W?p=preview

Comment: I have no choice but using `^=` selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself

I thought `^=` selector would take each class in `class=""` and check if one starts with the selector. But I was wrong. It checks the very beginning of `class=""`.

And actually my code looks more like that :

```
<span class="foo bar bg-client">Lorem ipsum</span>
<span class="foo bar bg-client_a">Lorem ipsum</span>
<span class="foo bar bg-client_b">Lorem ipsum</span>
<span class="foo bar bg-client_c">Lorem ipsum</span>
```

And this works :

```
[class^="bg-client"], [class*=" bg-client"] {}
```